# Rails form for creation of model and adding relation to other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture, controller

I have two models. Writers and Books.
A writer has many books.
After i have created writers, I want to add books to him or her.
In my `/writers/1` path i show the writers information and i have a list of his books.
When adding a book, i navigate to the `/books/new` path.

When i create the book, i want to create the relation to the writer.

What is the best solution to do this? Should I pass the writer to the `books/new` path?
Or is there another (better) solution?

Comment: You can set a hidden field for writer_id in new form of books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all books belong to an author, you're going to want to use nested resources.  You can read about [nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).